# When should I send geometric information over a topic as opposed to TF?

Tags: ros, geometry-msgs, best-practices, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please help in writing up a ROS best practice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11837/when-should-i-send-geometric-information-over-a-topic-as-opposed-to-tf?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some cases when tf is less suitable:

- The coordinate frames naturally form a graph rather than a tree (e.g., a slam graph).
- There is frequent reparenting of frames (e.g., a robot which is localized w.r.t. a changing local frame rather than a global one)
- The transformations include additional information such as uncertainty estimates not present in the TF message type.
- For efficiency, in situations where there are a large number of frames, most of which are only of interest to a few subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-07-02**:
Added: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Patterns/Communication#Publishing_Spatial_.2BAC8_Geometric_Data

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suitable for:
Robot joints, links, Sensor coordinate frames, and any other coordinate system that is going to be used as reference.

Not suitable for:
Very noisy data.

Also consider:
Using a topic rather than tf means you can more easily record / replay the data with rosbag/rxbag, as well as transfer the data between multiple robots.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-12-09**:
"more easily record/replay"?? All tf data is simply published on the /tf topic. You will have to "rosparam set use_sim_time true" to get most nodes to deal with TF data from the past, but recording/replaying that data isn't very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience, I find tf useful for real-time, single-estimation data; this breaks down when you want one to apply a correction to a geometric relationship in the past (like when a loop closure occurs during SLAM, and you want to use this new information to update the entire robot's path history), or when you have a couple things estimating the same transform (like odometry and laser scan matching, or two robots looking at the same thing). There are some ways to make tf do what you want in these cases, but they don't exhibit the same simplicity and elegance that tf shows for the real-time, single-estimation case.

Multi-robot tf over wifi, as others mentioned, won't work like you want it to out of the box. But a fairly lightweight fix is to use multiple /tf topics, say /robot_model_bandwidth_hog/tf and /i_wanna_communicate_these_few_transforms_to_other_robots/tf

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-07-02**:
Added: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Patterns/Communication#Publishing_Spatial_.2BAC8_Geometric_Data